# In JSP page I want to get IP address of user who view the page. How?

Tags: java, jsp, ip-address

In JSP page I want to get IP address of user who view the page. How can ?

Comment: What is the underlying problem you need to solve?

Answer (score 11):

Since *scriptlets* (those `<% %>` things) are discouraged since a decade, here's the EL solution:

```
<p>Your IP address is: ${pageContext.request.remoteAddr}</p>
```

If you actually intend to use this for some business purposes rather than displaying purposes, then you should be using a servlet. It's then available by [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteAddr()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29).

Answer (score 6):

```
<%= request.getRemoteAddr() %>
```

> Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request. For HTTP servlets, same as the value of the CGI variable REMOTE_ADDR.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @Lauri's answer.

If the request came via a proxy, there should be a ["Via" header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.45) in the request.

However, there is *no way* to figure out what the real client IP address if there are any intermediate proxies.  And a lot of peoples' browsers use proxies, whether or not they are aware of it.

Answer (score 2):

Luri's answer

```
<%= request.getRemoteAddr() %>
```

doesn't provide the IP Address Of Client who requested the URl, but would only provide the IP assigned to Server.

If the request comes via a proxy then you can use this :

```
request.getHeader("X_FORWARDED_FOR")
```

it will provide the IP of client.